# duplicate key value violates unique constraint setval settings

Tags: postgresql

I am reinstalling my database on a new laptop and am getting this error:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "cashflow_cashflow_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(4852) already exists.

Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    duplicate key value violates unique constraint "cashflow_cashflow_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(4852) already exists.
```

I found this, but cant get the right combination of values to work with my table.

```
SELECT setval('user_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM user));
```

Is this the right way to correct and how do I adjust for my table settings?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work. thanks.

SELECT setval('cashflow_cashflow_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM cashflow_cashflow)+1);